# Where to find the tomcat folder in the docker image

Tags: tomcat, docker, boot2docker

I'm using ubuntu and I have installed Docker and started my first tutorial using Tomcat.

I made a docker file named `Dockerfile` that contains

```
FROM tomcat:7-jre7
MAINTAINER "Craig Trim <craigtrim@gmail.com>"
```

Then I build the image using

```
sudo docker build -t craig/tomcat .
```

and finally I started Tomcat:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 craig/tomcat
```

Now in the console, it shows that Tomcat is installed somewhere in `/usr/local/tomcat`

```
4-Nov-2016 10:36:57.031 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web     application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
```

But when I go there I did not find the folder `tomcat`. Where to find that folder, so that I can configure some files?

Comment: What is the output of `docker logs <container id>`?

Comment: Were you looking for the directory inside the container or on the host?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran the apache container in the background (`-d`):

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 tomcat:7-jre7
```

I checked if the container was running

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
c2ca0d66536c        tomcat:7-jre7       "catalina.sh run"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   focused_bell
```

I went 'inside' the container using its container ID:

```
docker exec -it c2ca0d66536c bash
root@c2ca0d66536c:/usr/local/tomcat#
```

Now I'm able to go inside the application directory `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager` :

```
root@c2ca0d66536c:/usr/local/tomcat# cd webapps/host-manager/
root@c2ca0d66536c:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager# ls
META-INF  WEB-INF  images  index.jsp  manager.xml
```

I hope this was your question? Because it was not very clear for me. If it wasn't I'll delete or edit the answer. I think your 'problem' was the fact you're running the container in the foreground.

Comment: just small question i want to see that in the UI(i mean in the ubuntu explorer ) how can i do that?

Comment: You mapped the port of your apache container (8080) on 8080 of the host. So normally you should see the main page of apache on localhost:8080 or IP:8080 (where IP is the public ip of your ubuntu?). Don't know if you're using a real server or a local vm. When you have a browser inside your ubuntu explorer you can just visit localhost:8080

Comment: no i wan to see the tomcat directory that i saw it in the bash in ubuntu explorer (tomcat contains webapp,include,conf,lib...)

Comment: You can only see that from inside your container. If you want to put something in that folder you have to write a COPY statement in your dockerfile to copy your apps in that folder in your container, or you can mount your applications inside that folder.

Comment: Thanks - exactly what i was looking for